# Pyresparser error "Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'" Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to use `pyresparser` in pycharm but it is showing this error:

```
File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 71, in prediction_result
    data = ResumeParser(cv_path).get_extracted_data()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyresparser\resume_parser.py", line 25, in __init__
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 51, in load
    return util.load_model(
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 427, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```